# upgrade Gnome / Evolution to 3.20?

Tags: gnome, upgrade, email, evolution

I am running Ubuntu-gnome 16.04LTS, and have begun to use the evolution for my email & PIM since Thunderbird will no longer be getting any love...

Evolution is showing version 3.18.5.2 yet 3.20 is out with 3.21 in the works.

I have tried upgrading Gnome to 3.20 through the steps indicated but it still shows gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.18.5

what did I miss?

TIA

Comment: "indicated steps" what steps? Since Ubuntu is not a rolling release distribution it will ship with software provided before the release date and only provide security updates.

Comment: the steps indicated here: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/05/install-gnome-3-20-ubuntu-16-04-lts

Comment: since I am not looking to go "testing" stage on this machine, I wanted to stick with 3.20 - mainly due to the differences in Evolution handling secure sync to Google with gmail & calendar. as a result, I did not add the "-staging' repository.

Comment: As you can see, evolution 3.20 is in the staging PPA https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3-staging